# How did the popularities of Roman given names evolve over time?

Tags: language-evolution, names, resource-request, inscription

When a new Roman was born, the parents would give their child a name ([*praenomen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praenomen)).
Since there is a significant number of known names, there must have been variations in their relative popularities across the Roman history.
I would like to know more about these variations.

What do we know about the changes in the popularities of given names in ancient Rome?
**Are there studies or resources on the evolution of relative popularities of Roman *praenomina*?**
A serious study in this direction requires a large number of names and approximate dates, the best source of which are probably inscriptions in graves.
There will certainly be a bias, as the name distribution may depend on wealth, location, and other factors which effect the making and durability of graves.
A good study acknowledges the bias and gives some results about popularity variations within a specific group of people — whether or not exactly identified — and that can hopefully give some insight to broader trends.

I would be delighted to find something similar to [the Finnish name service](https://verkkopalvelu.vrk.fi/nimipalvelu/default.asp?L=3) when restricted to first names.
While I understand that information with this level of detail may be unlikely or impossible for the Roman world, I hope it gives an idea of what I am after.
I am not aware of any kind of onomastic databases for ancient Rome.

Comment: I am not aware of digitised onomastic databases for Ancient Rome, but there are some in print, e.g., Der kleine Pauly https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Kleine_Pauly

Answer (score 2):

When you can read German, [here](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/6197-mommsen-1.htm) is a transcript from Theodor Mommsen's work on Roman praenomina. It deals with the time of the Roman republic and the Augustean era.

A list of names with attribution to the Roman gentes is given in [part 5 of the transcript](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/6218-mommsen-5.htm).